# Как настроить вебпак для автоматической обработки множества страниц

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug

Я сделал сборку на webpack, в которой pug файлы генерируются из общей папки ".src/pages/". Как создать отдельную папку для каждого .pug файла в ".src/pages/" и при этом сохранить автоматическую обработку страниц по указанному пути вебпаком? Должно получится что-то типа "./src/pages/*base*/*base*.pug" для всех файлов.

Расположение файлов:

[image]

Webpack.config.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PATHS = {
    src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
    dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    assets: './assets/'
  };
const PAGES_DIR = `${PATHS.src}/pages/`;
const PAGES = fs.readdirSync(PAGES_DIR).filter(fileName => fileName.endsWith('.pug'));
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    },
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: 'base.html'
          },
        open: true,
        port: 3000,
        hot: true,
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
          },
          compress: true,
          port: 3000,
    },
    plugins: [
        new FaviconsWebpackPlugin('./src/theme/favicon.svg'),
            ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
                filename: `./${page.replace(/\.pug/,'.html')}`
              })),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                loader: 'pug-loader',
                options: {
                    pretty: true
                  }
              },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: "assets/pics/[name][ext]"
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: "assets/fonts/[name][ext]"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить путь `./${page}/` в filename:

```
            ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
                filename: `./${page}/${page.replace(/\.pug/,'.html')}`,
              })),
```

Либо отдельной строкой `publicPath:`

```
             ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: `${PAGES_DIR}/${page}`,
                filename: `./${page.replace(/\.pug/,'.html')}`,
                publicPath: `./${page}/`,
              })),
```

Документация https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#options

Если по каким-то причинам не работают оба способа, тогда пробуйте под `entry:` прописать `output:`, обратившись к рабочему объекту webpack'a `pathdata.chunk`

```
  output: {
    filename:            pathdata => getFilename(pathdata.chunk.name, 'js'), // ваша функция для получения имени
    path:                path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist' + (pathdata => getDirHTMLPages(pathdata.chunk.name)), //другая функция 
    assetModuleFilename: '[name][ext]',
```